# How to efficiently change the rightmost value in list of unknown depth?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that I've built up recursively (the function finds the component parts needed in a SQL query for a table that has nested partitions).  The table looks like this if there are 2 partition levels (in this case, theyear and themonth):

```
[[['theyear', '>=', 2014], ['OR'], ['theyear', '==', 2014, 'AND', [['themonth', '>=', 8], ['OR'], ['themonth', '==', 8, 'AND', False]]]], [['theyear', '<=', 2015], ['OR'], ['theyear', '==', 2015, 'AND', [['themonth', '<=', 9], ['OR'], ['themonth', '==', 9, 'AND', False]]]]]
```

What I'd like to do is simplify

```
['themonth', '>=', 8], ['OR'], ['themonth', '==', 8, 'AND', False]
```

to get just:

```
['themonth', '==', 8]
```

But the nested list can be of any depth (for example, a table could be partitioned by 'theyear', 'themonth', 'theday', 'thehour').  I know the depth=2 in the example, but I'm struggling to figure out how to automatically change the value of mylist[0][-1][-1] ... and change mylist[0][-1][-1][-1][-1] if the depth=4.

A simpler way to say this, is if I have

```
a = [3, [4, [5]]]
```

And I know the depth is 3, I can't just use a while loop to essentially do

```
b = a[-1]
b = b[-1]
b = [6]
>>> a
[3, [4, [5]]]
```

How can I define a function to change the rightmost value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def changeLast(nested, new):
    last = nested[-1]
    if isinstance(last, list):
        changeLast(last, new)
    else:
        nested[-1] = new

a = [3, [4, [5]]]
changeLast(a, 6)
print(a)

[3, [4, [6]]]
```

I haven't done any error-checking.  In particular, I don't know how you would want to deal with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You either need a loop or do it recursively. Then for each level check if the item is a list with `isinstance()`. If it isn't you found the deepest list.

Here's an iterative approach:

```
def get_rightmost(l):
  while True:
    try:
      # get last item of current list
      item = l[-1]
    except IndexError:
      # empty list, return it
      return l
    # check if item is a list
    if isinstance(item, list):
      # continue with the list in the last item
      l = item
    else:
      # return the current list
      return l
```

To change the rightmost value, set the last element of the returned list:

```
 rightmost_list = get_rightmost(your_list)
 rightmost_list[-1] = new_value # might fail with IndexError if list is empty.
 # So add a try-except block if you can't be sure the lists are never empty
```

Comment: I should add a warning: You need to make sure that your input contains no self-references. `l = []; l.append(l); get_rightmost(l)` will never terminate, as the depth is infinite. In your case that probably won't happen, but if someone uses this on unchecked user input: you have been warned :-)